# Postmapping - why is it working without a model?

Tags: java, spring, post, controller, thymeleaf

I've started to learn Spring recently, and I have written a really simple "app" to understand how it handles get and post requests and controllers. Basically what it does is just that it **gets** some kind of **value** from the **input text** and souts it to make sure that I can work with it in the program later on.

My codes are:

```
<form th:action="@{/main/form2}" th:method="post">
<input th:object="${postdata}" placeholder="Write it here..." 
name="postdata">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

**AND**

```
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping("/form")
    public String getInfo() {
        return "form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/form2") //end point name
    public String postInfo(@ModelAttribute("postdata") String receivedData){
        System.out.println(receivedData);

        //ModelAttribute: what you get from the HTML.
        //It works, even if i do not have a model

        return "redirect:/main/form"; //HTML name

    }
}
```

My questions are the following:

1. Why is it working without instantiating an object from the Model class and 
   adding this model attribute to it? Do I only need a model when I communicate 
   in the other direction, so when I send some values from Spring to the html 
   page?
2. Is it proper to do it this way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what did you mean by *"if i do not have a model"*?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I mean instantiating an object from the Model class to add the ModelAttribute to it.

Comment: AFAIK, a `Model` instance will be constructed for you automatically by Spring according to the properties that come in. You could inject the `Model` object or any part of it as a `@ModelAttribute`.